# How to stop client from reconnecting to server when the server is down?

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database

How can we stop a client from reconnecting to the server after some retries.

In our case (in memory DB for fast retrieval), we have used Ignite and Oracle in parallel so that if Ignite server is down, then I could get my data from Oracle.

But when I start my application (while the Ignite server node is down for some reason), my application always waiting until it connects to server.

Console message:

> Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2000 ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a TcpDiscoverySpi.joinTimeout property, which does exactly what you want: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/TcpDiscoverySpi.html#setJoinTimeout-long-

By default, it's not defined, so, node will try to reconnect endlessly.